# How can the community user know whether an edit is good?

Tags: discussion

Title says it all.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/323144, the edit was proposed by an anonymous user who didn't have a AU account. Therefore, the Community account is shown as the editor instead.

Comment: Ah. Will accept after the timer expires :)

Comment: @AndroidDev I was worried for a second that Skynet was upon us...

Comment: It was pretty strange, I'll say that :)